# sed replace file2 content with file3 content in file1

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

**H**ow to search file1 for file2 contents and replace them with file3 contents using sed?

file1 "multiline"

```
<DB>
    <Person><Name>Zack</Name>
        <PersonData>...</PersonData>
    </Person>
    <Person><Name>Dave</Name>
        <PersonData>...</PersonData>
    </Person>
    <Person><Name>Lisa</Name>
        <PersonData>...</PersonData>
    </Person>
    <Person><Name>Zack</Name>
        <PersonData>...</PersonData>
    </Person>
</DB>
```

file2 "multiline"

```
    <Person><Name>Zack</Name>
        <PersonData>...</PersonData>
    </Person>
```

file3 "multiline"

```
    <Employee><Name>Zack</Name>
        <EmployeeData>...</EmployeeData>
    </Employee>
```

I'm trying to replace every Zack person with an employee.
I've tried from simple

```
sed -i -r -e '1h;2,$H;$!d;g' -e "/PLACEHOLDER/ r $2" -e "s/PLACEHOLDER// $3" $1
```

to even more without any successful sed operation in order to change file1 to:

```
<DB>
    <Employee><Name>Zack</Name>
        <EmployeeData>...</EmployeeData>
    </Employee>
    <Person><Name>Dave</Name>
        <PersonData>...</PersonData>
    </Person>
    <Person><Name>Lisa</Name>
        <PersonData>...</PersonData>
    </Person>
    <Employee><Name>Zack</Name>
        <EmployeeData>...</EmployeeData>
    </Employee>
</DB>
```

---

Edit #1: Employee xml tags are completely different from person tags.
Edit #2: I'm not parsing xml, am trying to replace occurrences only through sed or awk.

Comment: sed is BAD tool for parsing xml

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest do you suggest awk or others?

Comment: nope, I can present a solution using proper xml parser. Are you able to apply it?

Comment: one more thing: this `..` considered to be the same in `file2` and `file3` ? Do you need to only replace the parent node `<Person>`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest no this `..` isn't the same in both files.

Comment: @AhmedGhoneim, can you extend your content to show how does `..` look?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest employees data completely differs from person data. I could use StaX if I was parsing this, but I'm not.

Comment: your files are somehow complicated for simple substitution. You need to expand your inner `...` from `file` to present the full path (with all child nodes) - then, this path(transformed) could be used while searching in `file1` without mentioning `file2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g;1s/.*/s#&#/;2s/.*/&#g/' file2 file3 | sed -z -f - file1
```

Create a substitution command from the match and replacement files (first quoting all newlines). Then apply the command against the source file.

Answer (score 0):

Consider also this bash solution:

```
$ cat file2
Name:John Due 
Gender:Male 
Age:21
Address: Texas

Name:Ed Mundo 
Gender:Male 
Age:41 
Address: California

$ cat file22
Name:Ed Mundo 
Gender:Male 
Age:41 
Address: California

$ cat file222
SurName:Ed Mundo 
Gender:Male 
Age:61 
Address: Chicago

$ a="$(<file22)";b="$(<file222)";c="$(<file2)"

$ echo "${c//$a/$b}"
Name:John Due 
Gender:Male 
Age:21
Address: Texas

SurName:Ed Mundo 
Gender:Male 
Age:61 
Address: Chicago
```